# PYTHON || PHP : Is there a way to understand the mood of a string?

Tags: php, python, machine-learning, semantics, sentiment-analysis

everyone.

I need this, if the user enters some string I want to understand the mood of that string:

- happy
- sad
- angry
- calm

It mustn't be exact like this, but I need something more precise than just positive/negative which comes with semantic analysis. Something that will give me about 4-5 mood options.

Comment: You can use the same pipeline as other supervised sentiment analysis methods—instead of positive or negative, your class labels are now the moods you're targeting.

Comment: @aryamccarthy thanks. But how can I separate positive/negative to for example 4-5 different moods?

Comment: From an information theoretic standpoint, you can't. If you're just working with positive or negative, you can't break that into anything more granular—the information has been lost. But if your training data is labeled according to mood, you're in business. You might be interested in [this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=4427099).

Comment: This question is very broad and out of scope for SO in its present form. You are asking for library or tutorial which can do this. Anyways, its not that easy too. You need a NLP engine which can do this or some pre-labeled data (somewhat large) on which you can train models on.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary of both the types of words after that give them equal weight age. After that,check the occurrence of listed words and calculate their weight age of string based on occurrence of words.

Comment: This is prone to one of the big pitfalls in sentiment analysis: your entire model falls to pieces if you put the word "not" in there.

Comment: So, what are other options instead of that?

Comment: The negation check is an important part of a complete pipeline. See [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.4944.pdf) for an overview.

Comment: thanks, you cleared one of my major doubts. Eventually, i used this method in a small project but negation was not working.